# How to use PagedList with in Parent Model - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

In My `Controller` & `View` i used different `Parent Modals` and in one of `Parent modals` which is `Comment_List` i want to use `PagedList` and I did it as you can see in my `Controller`, but when it comes to `View` it's confusing me I don't know which `Modals` (`Main` or `Parent`) should I wrap in `IPagedList`.

Models :

```
public class VMRMA
    {

    public List<Comment_List> Comment_Lists { get; set; }

        public class Comment_List
        {
            public Comment_List(string PM, int? ID , string writer)
            {
                this.PM = PM;
                this.ID = ID;
                this.writer = writer;    
            }


            public int? ID { get; set; }           
            public string PM { get; set; }
            public string writer { get; set; }
        }

      public HRMA HRMAs { get; set; }

        public class HRMA
        {
            public HRMA(int Id,string Kundenavn)
            {
                this.Id = Id;
                this.Kundenavn = Kundenavn;
            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Kundenavn { get; set; }

        }
  }
```

View:

```
@using ModelNameSpace.Models
@model VMRMA

//single
<input type="text" class="form-control disabled" value="@Model.HRMAs.Kundenavn">

//List
@foreach (var item in Model.Comment_Lists)
{

 <div class="card-body no-padding">
   <div class="item d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="text">
  <h3 class="h5">@item.PM</h3>
   <small>Til @item.writer</small>
     </div>
</div>
 </div>
  }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult RMA(int? id, VMRMA model , int? pageNumber)
    {

        //List comments
          IPagedList<VMRMA.Comment_List> queryTwo = (from RH in db.RMA_History

                       join RB in db.Besked on RH.Id equals RB.RMAID

                       where RB.RMAID == id 

                       select new VMRMA.Comment_List
                       {
                           //Select Something

                       }).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 3);


          var query = (from RH in db.RMA_History
                       join RS in db.RMAStatus on RH.StatusID equals RS.ID


                      where RH.Id == id


                       select new VMRMA.HRMA
                       {
                           //Select Something

                       });

        model.HRMAs = query.FirstOrDefault();
        model.Comment_Lists = queryTwo.ToList();

        return View(model);
   }
```

Comment: Your property should be `public IPageList<Comment_List> Comment_Lists { get; set; }` and remove the `.ToList()` in `model.Comment_Lists = queryTwo;`, but you do not appear to have included `@Html.PageListPager(Model.Comment_Lists, .... )` in your view

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke  :) so if i dont appear to have PageListPager in my view , wat should i do than ! can i use PartialView instead?!

Comment: You need to include `@using PagedList;` and `@using PagedList.Mvc;` in the view, and then add `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Comment_Lists, page => Url.Action("RMA", new { page }))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just get small problem ,when i in page 1 my URL its like this : http://localhost/User/RMA?Id=129 ,when i go to page two i get error and my URL will be like this : http://localhost/User/RMA?page=2 but it should be something like http://localhost:49870/User/RMA?id=129&page=2 , would you please tell me how can  i modified that :)

Comment: Then you also need to include the `id` in the route values - e.g. `new { page, id = 129 }` (but instead of hardcoding it, you would pass it via a view model property or a `ViewBag` property - e.g. `new { page, id = Model.ID }`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did something like this    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Comment_Lists, page => Url.Action("RMA", new { page , id=Model.HRMAs.Id })) and result will be like this  http://localhost/User/RMA/129?page=2 but it didnt pass id parameters i mean like this http://localhost/User/RMA?Id=129&page=2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176804/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-7-seconds).